# Dask Dataframe read_sql_table returns TypeError

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, dask

Trying the following code

```
alerts = df.read_sql_table('alerts', db_url, index_col='id', npartitions=16)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-d14f44b5a2c5> in <module>()
----> 1 alerts = df.read_sql_table('alerts', db_url, index_col='id', npartitions=16)

/home/avlach/virtualenvs/dask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.pyc in read_sql_table(table, uri, index_col, divisions, npartitions, limits, columns, bytes_per_chunk, **kwargs)
121             divisions[-1] = maxi
122         else:
--> 123             divisions = np.linspace(mini, maxi, npartitions + 1).tolist()
124 
125     parts = []

/home/avlach/virtualenvs/dask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.pyc in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype)
106     # Convert float/complex array scalars to float, gh-3504
107     # and make sure one can use variables that have an __array_interface__, gh-6634
--> 108     start = asanyarray(start) * 1.0
109     stop  = asanyarray(stop)  * 1.0
110 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

DB schema is the following:

```
describe alerts;
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| description       | text     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| channel_id        | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| score             | float    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| raised_at         | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| activity_earliest | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| activity_latest   | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I cannot understand the error. Table is empty for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this line [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py#L105). When no limits are set it tries to find the limits by querying for the max and min index of the table. But if no data are on the table it returns None for both max and min. Thus when trying to get [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py#L123) `np.linspace` raises exception for None values for `mini` and `maxi`

Is there any mechanism for handling empty Database tables when using `read_sql_table`?